# Electric field near surface of conductor derivation

Tags: electrostatics

In page-50 of I.E irodov Basic Laws of Electromagnetism, he derives the relation for the force on surface of a conductor by every other charge distributed across the rest of the surface area.

The proof goes as follows: Let $E_{\sigma}$  be the intensity of field created by the charge on surface area, let $ E_0$ be the field created by rest of the charges.

[image]

Inside the conductor, for electrostatic equilibrium:

$$ E_0 - E_{\sigma} = 0 \tag{1}$$

Near the surface:

$$ E =  E_0 + E_{\sigma} = 2E_o \tag{2}$$

After some more algebra, we can write:

$$F= \frac{\epsilon_o E^2}{2} \hat{n}$$

My doubt is how we can we say that the fields caused by each surface area portion under consideration for inside portion and outside portion are equal in magnitude?

As in, how do we know:

$$ E_{\sigma inside} = E_{\sigma outside}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start considering a small charged planar disc of surface $\Delta S$, which remains the same if you mirror it. The magnitude of the field is then the same below and above the disc by symmetry. See also [these lecture notes, example 2.1.3](http://web.mit.edu/sahughes/www/8.022/lec02.pdf#page=3) for the calculation of the field of a disc.

When you then shrink the area to the point that its size becomes negligible with respect to the distance at which you calculate the field, the shape becomes then irrelevant because you can consider it a point charge. And this has a symmetric field too.

Comment: I was doing another question which involved considering the infinitesimal area as a thing 'rubber band' ring which wrapped around a sphere. Now, how do I apply this arguement I said to that case?

Comment: @Buraian If the problem is that of calculating the field generated by a hollow sphere, than you cannot apply the same argument, because the size of the ring is generally not negligible with respect to the distance between the ring and the point at which you calculate the field. But if the sphere is uniformly charged, then the ring has again mirror symmetry, and the field is symmetric.